# TM1638 making high pitch sound?

Tags: arduino-uno, sound

I have a TM1638 board with 8 seven-segment displays, 8 LEDS, and 8 buttons. Each time multiples leds are on, the board makes an annoying high pitch sound.

I'm controlling it with an Arduino Uno.

Should I worry about the sound and is it normal?

This is my board :

[image]

Comment: What board do you have?

Comment: check your ground connections

Comment: Where does the sound come from exactly? When your LEDs are on, they draw power from the power supply. Cheap switching power supplies will exhibit a ringing sound under load (Spulenfiepen / coil whining, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetically_excited_acoustic_noise_and_vibration#Reduction_of_%22coil_noise%22)

Comment: I would guess it is a harmonic from the multiplex signal. Touch each part with a pencil eraser and see if it goes away.  Can you change the voltage by maybe 0.02 volts and see if it changes. Without a schematic I can only guess. I have seen these symptoms before but not with this hardware.

Answer (score 1):

This thread is getting old but this LED&KEY device seems to still be fairly popular so this may still help someone else. I'm using one to control a radio receiver and the constant buzz can get pretty loud.

I found [this article](https://nerdralph.blogspot.com/2018/06/a-second-look-at-tm1638-led-key.html?lr=1) (A second look at the TM1638 LED & key controller) which mentions the same issue which was solved by inserting a 100Ω resistor between VCC and the VCC pin. I also added a 1000μF electrolytic capacitor across the VCC and GND pins (well, fairly close to them anyway). This quieted down the buzz a lot though it's still there. The resistor is key though the capacitor helps a bit.

I also tried moving the breadboard connections to a separate, smaller breadboard, away from the MCU and radio receiver chip and was able to use lower values (10Ω and 47μF). I was no longer able to hear the buzz at all.